# European/UK sources for quality book weight duo coated inkjet paper?

Tags: printing, books

Im doing some research on inkjet book-weight duo papers, something that performs well for photo and graphics.

I work at an art school in Scotland and am not finding much on the market that is below 200gsm, which for book is quite a lot. Our photo students have a book assignment that has them making bound photo book portfolios on our Epson 4880.

I am already familiar with the RedRiver papers, but so far haven't found a distributor that carries their products here in the UK or Europe.

Does anyone have any tips?

Thanks from Scotland

PS - I've already seen this [post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16704/what-double-sided-ink-jet-paper-is-best-for-printing-fine-art-photo-books-at-hom)

Answer (score 1):

The only two papers that I know of that are double sided (duo) ink jet papers are from RedRiver. The Arctic Polar Luster DS is a great paper, although it is barely less than 200gsm (weighing in at 190gsm). This is my personal choice for book prints. They also have an even lighter weight matte paper, at 125gsm, although I've never used it.

Illford also has a duo luster, however it is 280gsm, a fair bit heavier than you are looking for. Museo also used to have a double-sided paper, I haven't seen it for sale anywhere for a while. It too weighted in too heavy, at 250gsm.

If you are willing to go with lesser quality, I am pretty sure you could find a light weight double sided ink jet paper from a cheaper off-brand manufacturer. You can often find papers from 90-180gsm, however I honestly couldn't tell you how the paper quality is. It is also unlikely you'll find ready-to-go ICC profiles for them, so you might be stuck sending a sheet off to have it profiled, or will have to generate a profile yourself.

Comment: Profiling isn't an issue, but I've not even found a off brand that claims double coated at less then 200gsm. If anyone knows of one, by all means chime in! It's killing me that Redriver haven't a Eurozone distributor.

Comment: Well, I know about papers in the US. [Here is one](http://www.amazon.com/Unibind-Double-Sided-8-5x11-Inkjet/dp/B004BFY72C/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1368284109&sr=8-6&keywords=double-sided+ink+jet+paper). It is 32lb (120gsm)...seems fairly cheap, but I couldn't find anything else that said double-sided and had any reference to the paper weight.